# Using PGRoute from OpenLayers via PostGIS/PostgreSQL

Tags: postgis, openlayers-2, pgrouting, json

I need to route a shortest distance for a map which I have loaded from a PostgreSQL by means of JSON file. I can project the map in my browser and I can identify the linestrings. For a particular linestring I wanted to check whether distance is calculated or not. Soon after, I would like to check among the different linestrings(nearest node). All I want is after marking start point and end point that route would calculate a distance. Here I could get vertices of a point when clicked.
Data I am having is a JSON file and PostgreSQL Server/DB, JScript, OpenLayers.  Moreover, I would like to display attributes over the linestring from the JSON file properties.

Is this possible?

I got stuck for the next step.